# Removing transitions when setting source data

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

When I use the default templates in Windows 8 Store apps for an item grid, I get some nifty transitions when the source of the collection is set. How can I remove these transitions?

I am doing a filter on the data and I dont like how the data fades in every time the data changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove them by overriding the ItemContainerTransitions. If you add the following style to the page resources:-

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="NoAnimations" TargetType="GridView">         
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
            <Setter.Value>
                <TransitionCollection>                        
                </TransitionCollection>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>           
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Then set the style of your gridview to NoAnimations:

```
<GridView Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource NoAnimations}">
```

That should take care of it for you. If you don't want to loose all of the animations then you can add some of them back - here is a list of the default animations on the gridview:-

```
<TransitionCollection>                       
    <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
    <ContentThemeTransition/>
    <ReorderThemeTransition/>
    <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
</TransitionCollection>
```