# Enable specific transitions only when a condition is true; Windows 8.1 App; C# XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-8

I am programming a Windows 8.1 App using C#/XAML as well as the MVVM-Light Toolkit.

In my program there is a GridView with ~40 Elements that represents a schedule whose items can be edited through clicking on them when an edit-mode is enabled. Every Time an item is clicked the ItemsSource is updated and thus the ContentThemeTransition causes some weird appearing visuals. I therefore disabled that transition.

However my App also enables the user to switch between different schedules. When he does that and when the Page is loaded I'd pretty much like the items in the GridView to update visually.
My question now is: Is it possible to set a condition so that the transition only fires when this condition is true?

I don't see any code in my program that is relevant to this question. And through research I haven't found an answer yet.

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a `IValueConverter` whose value you bind to the `Style` property of your `GridView` and to a bool value which represents whether the transition should be visible or not. As a parameter for your converter you can set a style for your gridview in which the transition is disabled. If the bool is true you can return the parameter, and if it's not, then you dont. Implied you use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980118/removing-transitions-when-setting-source-data) to disable the transitions.