# Flickering when ListView updates

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8.1

I've got a ListView in WindowsPhone 8.1 which is often refreshed and every time it causes a flicker.

I already tried these solutions but nothing worked:

1. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e7b6b664-c4f8-4ebf-83a2-02751041ef5c/disable-listview-animation-when-items-update?forum=winappswithcsharp
2. [Removing transitions when setting source data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13980118/removing-transitions-when-setting-source-data)

Does anyone have another solution?

Comment: Can you provide a working sample app? Had a similar issue some time back, but don't remember the exact solution. I'd just compare if you provide a sample.

Comment: Unfortunately no. It would be a lot of work. For me that would be the last try.

Answer (score -1):

I kinda found this thread, providing a solution for the problem with `flickering` of the `ListView`.

> The problem appears to be that the control's Update overload is improperly implemented such that it acts like a Refresh

Reference: [c# flickering Listview on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442817)

Comment: There a lot of old threads, but until now I didn't find a working solution for the WPH 8.1. Most of them are talking about setting the doublebuffered property. But as far as I know this property doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: This is a solution for WPF applications, not Windows Phone 8.1